# PHP login form not functioning

Tags: php, html

I have written code for a login page in PHP. When I submit the log in details, the page is simply being redirected to itself even though I have written a code to redirect to a different page. Please help me identify where the mistake is.

The code looks like this

```
<?php
session_start();

    $username = $password= "";
    $usernameErr = $passwordErr = "";
    $empty = false;

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]))
        {
            $empty = true;
            $usernameErr="Username is empty. Please try again";
        }
        else 
            {
                $username = $_POST["username"];
            }
        if(empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $empty = true;
            $passwordErr="Password is empty. Please try again";
        }
        else 
            {
                $password = $_POST["password"];
            }
        if(!$empty)
        {
            $servername = "myxor.in.mysql";
            $dbusername = "myxor_in";
            $dbpassword = "srikanth177";
            $dbname = "myxor_in";
            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) 
            {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "SELECT firstname,password,package FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if (($result->num_rows) > 0) 
            {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();


                    if($username === $row['username']) 
                    {
                        if($password === $row['password'])
                        {
                            echo "came here";
                            $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['firstname'];
                            $_SESSION['pack'] = $row['package'];
                            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                            header("Location: http://www.myxor.in/home.php");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $passwordErr = "Invalid Password. Please Try Again";
                        }
                    }

            } else
            {
                $usernameErr = "Invalid Username. Please Try Again";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<head>
  <style>
  td{
       color:red;
      }
  </style>
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2 align=center style="color:blue">Login Form</h2>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<table align=center bgcolor=grey >
<tr>
    <td><label>UserName :</label>
    <td><input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
    <td><?php echo $usernameErr?></td>
<tr>
    <td><label>Password :</label>
    <td><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
    <td><?php echo $passwordErr?></td>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 align=center><input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `header("Location: ")` cannot come after you've output content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help. I found the error myself. The error is that I am trying to access 'username' from the row without selecting username in the query. So it is malfunctioning. I rectified it by adding username column in the select list. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the problem is:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
```

You are sending the form to the same url the form is being displayed with $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] (which is actually valid unless you want to send the form to another URL like in your case). Change the action to the URL you want to send the form to for validation. E.g.

```
<form action="validate_form.php" method="post">
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("validations.php");

$username = "";
$password= "";
$usernameErr = $passwordErr = "";
$empty = false;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])
{
    if(empty($_POST["username"]))
    {
        $empty = true;
        $usernameErr="Username is empty. Please try again";
    }
    else 
        {
            $username = $_POST["username"];
        }
    if(empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $empty = true;
        $passwordErr="Password is empty. Please try again";
    }
    else 
        {
            $password = $_POST["password"];
        }
    if(!$empty)
    {
        $servername = "myxor.in.mysql";
        $dbusername = "myxor_in";
        $dbpassword = "srikanth177";
        $dbname = "myxor_in";
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT firstname,password,package FROM users WHERE         username='$username'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if (($result->num_rows) > 0) 
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();


                if($username === $row['username']) 
                {
                    if($password === $row['password'])
                    {
                        echo "came here";
                        $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['firstname'];
                        $_SESSION['pack'] = $row['package'];
                        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                        header('Location: http://www.myxor.in/home.php');
                        exit;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $passwordErr = "Invalid Password. Please Try Again";
                    }
                }

        } else
        {
            $usernameErr = "Invalid Username. Please Try Again";
        }
    }
}
?>

<head>
  <style>
  td{
   color:red;
  }
  </style>
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h2 align=center style="color:blue">Login Form</h2>
    <form action="this_page.php"  method="post">
<table align=center bgcolor=grey >
<tr>
<td><label>UserName :</label>
<td><input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<td><?php echo $usernameErr?></td>
<tr>
<td><label>Password :</label>
<td><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="********** type="password">
<td><?php echo $passwordErr?></td>
<tr>
 <td colspan=2 align=center><input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login     ">
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And you had: `$username = $password = "";`
I corrected it to `$username = ""; $password="";`

And I changed some of the html
What I changed in the html is the form action to be a page not just `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">`

I changed it to: `<form action="yourpagevalidation.php" method="post">`

And I added exit after your `header`

And I changed Your `if($_REQUEST[]` stuff to `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: yes @camelCase i am changing now

Comment: Thanks, that'll help. Just a heads up that `$username = $password = ""` is _valid_ although IMHO bad practice. I agree with your adjustments but the original wouldn't cause an error.

Comment: @camelCase i know it is valid but it is a better practice to do the way i did

Comment: @camelCase please up vote

Comment: I tried with the changes you made. The page is being redirected to validate.php but neither an output is being displayed even though I 'echo'ed a line nor the page is redirected from validate.php as I used the header("Location: http://myxor.in/home.php") function call.

Comment: @YSV i edited my post try it now

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
```